# SSAS Cube attribute value case got changed ( 'Abc') after Cube Full process, even though underlying data is in upper case (‘ABC’)

Tags: attributes, ssas, settings, collation

I noticed that sometimes SSAS Cube dimension member value case is differ from data source after Cube process .

Example: 
(Database Field Value) ABC  ---> Abc (Cube Dimension attribute value)

Language/Collation Settings:

Windows Collation: Latin1_General
Accent-Sensitive
Kana-Sensitive
Width-Sensitive

Language : 
English(United States)

Note: 
•   This is an intermittent issue.
•   Dimension, Cube collation settings are same as Server level settings.
•   There are No changes to data source values.
•   Cube Database Processing mode : “Process Full”
•   SQL Server Version: 2012

Thanks
Naresh

Comment: What's the collation of the SQL database? Do you have some ABC rows and some Abc?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Do you have some ABC rows and some Abc in SQL? If so then the behavior you are getting is expected. What behavior do you want? If you want it not to change case then update the rows in SQL making it consistent in SQL.

Comment: @GregGalloway Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS . 

I see only 'ABC' in Cube data now. But source data has same field value in different cases (‘abc,’ABC’ & ‘Abc’) .
As cube settings are set to Case Insensitive and cube relevant SQL queries do not have an order by clause , cube attribute value case may differ after cube process.

Thanks for your hint!